# Stone Weirstrass clarification

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ and the set of functions $A=\{e^{int} \mid n \in \mathcal{Z}\}$. $A$ is a set which separates points and contains the constant functions. Why can't we conclude from Stone Weierstrass theorem that $\bar{A}=C[-\pi,\pi]$?

I know that $\bar{A}=C[-\pi,\pi]_0$

Comment: Clearly this is not my field of expertise, but what does $C[-\pi,\pi]_0$ mean? I read that as compactly supported functions, but surely that's not right.

Comment: $A$ doesn't separate points. $f(\pi) = f(-\pi)$ for all $f\in A$.

Comment: $C[-\pi,\pi]_0$ is the set of periodical (continuous ) functions on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: OK, thanks @DanielFischer