# How to fix this argument that the periodic functions on $[-L/2,L/2]$ generate a dense subspace of $L^2[-L/2,L/2]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

In V. Moretti's "Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics," example 3.32 (1), he attempts to show that the functions

$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{i\frac{2\pi n}{L}x},$$

where $n\in\mathbb Z,x\in[-L/2,L/2]$ for fixed $L>0$, generate a dense subspace of $L^2[-L/2,L/2]$. But I think his argument is wrong, as confirmed by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458944/stone-weirstrass-clarification) and discussed by me below. **My question is, how can we most easily correct this proof, preferably without resorting to an entirely different method?**

Let $S=\operatorname{span}\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Moretti's approach is to show that $S$ is dense in $C[-L/2,L/2]$ (the continuous functions from $[-L/2,L/2]$ to $\mathbb C$), and then that $C[-L/2,L/2]$ is dense in $L^2[-L/2,L/2]$. But to show that $S$ is dense in $C[-L/2,L/2]$, he invokes the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, which requires that $S$ separates points in $[-L/2,L/2].$ From what I can tell (and as is similarly claimed in the above-linked post), $S$ does not separate the endpoints $-L/2$ and $L/2$. Can this approach still be salvaged, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is essentially correct. The fix is to prove the density instead on the torus, ie. $[-L/2,L/2]$ with the endpoints quotiented together. Then they are the same point, so there’s nothing to separate! (Note that S-W still works on a compact Hausdorff space.) Then since null sets don’t matter, $L^2$ on the torus is naturally identified with $L^2$ on this interval.

Comment: Many of these answers seem correct, but I like this one because it is concise and provides topological insight.

Comment: Though I think there's an additional step worth mentioning, where we need to show that continuous functions on the torus are $L^2$-dense in continuous functions on the interval. Unless there's a way around this that I'm missing.

Comment: The way I’m thinking about it, you prove density of the Fourier basis in $C^0(\mathbb T^1)$ which implies density in $L^2(\mathbb T^1)$. Then, you observe that $L^2(\mathbb T^1)$ and $L^2([-L/2,L/2])$ are the same space since the endpoints are a null set.

Comment: Ah ok. I was worried about continuous functions on $[-L/2,L/2]$ without $f(-L/2)=f(L/2)$. But these are approximated by continuous functions on the torus, so $C^0(\mathbb{T}^1)$ still completes to $L^2(\mathbb{T}^1),$ even though $L^2(\mathbb{T}^1)$ includes functions like $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

You salvage the approach by showing that the continuous functions such that $f(-L/2)=f(L/2)$ are dense in $L^2$. This is easy to show as you can always consider a small interval around a point where you don't need to approximate your function.

That is, given $f\in L^2$ and $\varepsilon>0$, find $g$ continuous with $\|f-g\|<\varepsilon/2$. Then define $h$ to be continuous, equal to $g$ on $[-L/2,L/2-\varepsilon^2/(2\|g\|_\infty)^2]$, with $\|h\|_\infty=\|g\|_\infty$, and with $h(-L/2)=h(L/2)$. Then
$$
\|f-h\|_2\leq \|f-g\|_2+\|g-h\|_2<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac{\varepsilon}2=\varepsilon.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $C_0[-L/2,L/2]$ for the subspace of $C[-L/2,L/2]$ consisting of the $f$
with $f(-L/2)=f(L/2)$. Then by Stone-Weierstrass, the $f_n$ generate an $L^2$-dense
subspace of $C_0[-L/2,L/2]$ and we know $C[-L/2,L/2]$ is $L^2$-dense in $L^2[-L/2,L/2]$.
To complete the proof we need that
$C_0[-L/2,L/2]$ is $L^2$ dense in $C[-L/2,L/2]$.

But $C_0[-L/2,L/2]$ has codimension $1$ in $C[-L/2,L/2]$, so we only need
to show that there's one function $h\in C[-L/2,L/2]$ but not in $C_0[-L/2,L/2]$
that can be $L^2$-approximated by functions in $C_0[-L/2,L/2]$. We can take $h(x)=x$
and write down a sequence in $C[-L/2,L/2]$ converging to $h$ in the $L^2$-norm.